# Is it possible to add an image in sqlite database from command line? If yes, how is it done?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, command-line

I need to create an sqlite database containing fields - name, price and icon - and then transfer the database to the android emulator so that it can be accessed by the code.
But i'm stuck with adding images to the database from command line. How do I go ahead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to convert images into blob. SQLLite can store blob values. And instead of adding data manaually using command line, why don't you use http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ . Much easier to do.